# python - TypeError: expected string or buffer on sql query

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an sql query that's returning the following value -

```
{'jobrun_deps': 'T=1 \x01ID=56494759 \x01DID=583887 \x01O=N \x01M=N \x01J=76732 \x01R=0 \x01P=1 \x01S=101 \x01WR=N \x01T=1 \x01ID=56494760 \x01DID=418400 \x01O=N \x01M=N \x01J=48064 \x01R=14780471 \x01P=1 \x01S=101 \x01WR=N \x01T=1 \x01ID=56494761 \x01DID=583889 \x01O=N \x01M=N \x01J=76733 \x01R=0 \x01P=1 \x01S=101 \x01WR=N \x01'}
```

So when I try to do this -

```
results = (re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', my_query))
```

I get this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scripts\OPS\TIDAL\dependency_check.py", line 25, in <module>
    results = (re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', my_query))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

This is because the re.findall is expecting it to not have the column name in the results.  how do I either change my re.findall to use the output I'm providing or change the sql query to give a string like it expects.

```
'T=1 \x01ID=56494759 \x01DID=583887 \x01O=N \x01M=N \x01J=76732 \x01R=0 \x01P=1 \x01S=101 \x01WR=N \x01T=1 \x01ID=56494760 \x01DID=418400 \x01O=N \x01M=N \x01J=48064 \x01R=14780471 \x01P=1 \x01S=101 \x01WR=N \x01T=1 \x01ID=56494761 \x01DID=583889 \x01O=N \x01M=N \x01J=76733 \x01R=0 \x01P=1 \x01S=101 \x01WR=N \x01'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of that `my_query` is a dictionary and you can not pass it to `re.findall` you need to pass the value of the dictionary :

```
results = (re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', my_query['jobrun_deps']))
```

Comment: Thanks!  knew it was going to be something simple.